# Push into an array elements of textbox

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a text box:

```
<input type="text" name="dropdiv" id="dropdiv" style="width:605" />
```

It contains more tags(elements,for example: first tag last tag second tag), and how I can put elements into an array after that insert into database using CodeIgniter?

Thx

Comment: if the raw input is like `tag1 tag2 tag3`, then just `explode()` it

Comment: Please explain better what you would like to do

Comment: Put elements from textbox into an array after that to insert into a table from database.I have table articles,tags,tag_in_articles and I want to associated item for article

Answer (score 0):

Try with `implode` to get as string

```
<input type="text" name="tags" value="<php echo implode(",", $tags); ?>" />
```

And explode tags to save database:

```
$tags = array_map('trim', explode(',', $this->input->post('tags')));
```